# Problemas Android Studio No Puedo Ejecutar Proyecto(Ide Error Ocurred)

Tags: android, android-studio

No se porque Andorid studio desde el día de ayer no me esta dejando ejecutar mis proyectos, me los carga bien pero al momento de darle RUN me muestra un mensaje  **Ide Error Ocurred**
Ya intente dandole **Clean Project y Rebuild Project** y aun no puedo solucionar el error.
al abrir el error me muestra esto
[image: Captura del Error]

Comment: Parece que es la maquina virtual de Android estuviera fallando , revisa este enlace donde alguien pregunto algo similiar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39036796/unable-to-locate-adb-using-android-studio

Answer (score 0):

desde el dia de ayer estuve con este problema, lo que hice fue descargar el [SDK](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platform-tools)  y pegar en la capeta de mi sdk locar el archivo adb que venia en la carpeta que descargue y con eso se soluciono

Aqui esta la [solucion](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DeZKmxt4jkI)